# Convert three lines into one line in linux

Tags: linux, converters

I am new in Unix.

I have the following file:

```
AB 123-01 vl 278
AB 123-01 na "aa"
AB 123-01 eg 5,6

AB 445-01 vl 521
AB 445-01 na "cd"
AB 445-01 eg 7,6

AB 945-01 vl 215
AB 945-01 na "Discreet"
AB 945-01 eg 1,6
```

I want to get the following output:

```
AB 123-01,278,aa,5,6
AB 445-01,521,cd,7,6
AB 945-01,215,Discreet,1,6
```

Convert three lines into one line with commas (always three lines)
And delete the words: vl, na, eg

Comment: I have a text file that I want to edit it as I mentioned.
I would like to know how i can do this by Unix commands?

Comment: Can the 4th field in the second line of each group - the field that's in double quotes - ever contain a comma?

Comment: I read this as: remove the third column, then group by the first two. Is that what you want?

Comment: No.
Each section has three rows, I want to group them into one line.

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer a one liner you can use awk.

Input filename.txt

```
AB 123-01 vl 278
AB 123-01 na "aa"
AB 123-01 eg 5,6

AB 445-01 vl 521
AB 445-01 na "cd"
AB 445-01 eg 7,6

AB 945-01 vl 215
AB 945-01 na "Discreet"
AB 945-01 eg 1,6
```

Code:

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS=NULL} {printf("%s %s,%s,%s,%s\n", $1, $2, $4, substr($8,2,length($8)-2), $12)}' filename.txt
```

Output

```
AB 123-01,278,aa,5,6
AB 445-01,521,cd,7,6
AB 945-01,215,Discreet,1,6
```